# ARCore – Max number of Anchors

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore, aranchor

I am wondering what is the max number of anchors that we can create in ARCore before the AR session crash? Let say, we place an anchor every 5 meters.

Answer (score 1):

The max number of anchors in ARCore app depends on several factors (on chipset, ARCore version, etc). There are `Local` anchors (Trackable and Session), `Cloud` anchors and `Geospatial` anchors. Each type of anchors has a different processing cost. However, in the context of Local anchors, I can say that `50 trackable anchors` is quite a heavy burden for ARCore processing.